# Unexpected Behavior with Rotation in SVG

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, rotation

I want to create a movable and rotatable shape with SVG. I've done that and this is [the link of the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCwZ5aYO2sVS1n6g87kL?p=preview). The code below is responsible for rotation:

```
scope.$watch('Rotation', function (newValues) {

      var rotateAngle = newValues || 0;

      newg.attr("transform","rotate(" + rotateAngle + " "+ (positionX + width / 2) +" "+ (positionY + height / 2) +")");
    });
```

The scenario below cause to an unexpected problem:

1. Rotating the shape(e.g. 20 deg)
2. Moving the shape to another position
3. Changing the rotation value

After the last step, The rotation operation works fine but the problem is the position of shape is changed to unexpected position. I want to keep the position of shape and rotate it without any extra movement.

**Update 1**

For preventing misunderstands I've captured a video which contains the scenario: 
[Check this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/up17wn80g0oovgh/RotationSVG.webm?dl=0).

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by *unexpected position*.

Comment: @RobertLongson Whenever I change the value of rotation I suppose to keep the shape at the current position, but as I mentioned in the scenario it's not working properly.

Comment: @RobertLongson I got his point, just do the operation that he said in his scenario. It is really strange.

Comment: I did, nothing strange happened. Perhaps it's a bug in the UA you're using, or perhaps I'm just not doing it right.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm using google chrome latest version, I want to rotate the shape by its center origin.

Comment: When you translate (move) the position you change the origin (point around which the shape is rotated) . You must rotate then translate. If you wish to rotate again then you must translate back to the origin then rotate then translate again. Or you can generate the matrix in code.

Comment: @RobertLongson Please check the update 1.